# Modified equation in Taylor series expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

Take any x ∈ R, u ∈ R, h > 0 and write the Taylor expansion

$$p(x + uh) = p(x) + p'(x)uh + · · · + \frac{(uh)^l}{(l-1)!} \int_0^1 (1-\tau)^{l-1}p^{l}(x+\tau uh) d\tau$$

$p^{l}(x)$ is nth derivative of $p(x)$

I don't understand the last term $\frac{(uh)^l}{(l-1)!} \int_0^1 (1-\tau)^{l-1}p^{l}(x+\tau uh) d\tau$ in the Taylor expansion formula

I think that's a little different from lagrange remainder

please tell me explanation in detail

Comment: Removing this useless $h$ everywhere would increase readability.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the [integral remainder](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Taylor#Formule_de_Taylor_avec_reste_int%C3%A9gral_de_Laplace) you are used to, and (even if they failed) your attempts (by change of variable) to prove that it equals the remainder you are wondering about.